# Place styles generated by material-ui for children components after style generated for parent component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I am using [material-ui](https://material-ui.com) which in turn uses [JSS](http://cssinjs.org/?v=v9.8.7) to style a website.

I have a component called `Layout` that sets margin of all its children (using all children selector `& > *` in its style). That works but I also want the children to be able to override that margin in their own styles named in `className` property.

This issue is caused by the fact that material-ui's `withStyle` function places the parent's style *after* children's styles inside html `<head>`. I could increase all chidren's style priority by doing something like `withStyles(classes, { index: 1 })(ChildComponent)` but that would be tedious and error prone.

What can I do to allow overriding parent defined style by children?

Also see [this request](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12899).

Comment: Can you please explain this question a bit more, I don't understand your intent? Do you want to update your generated JSS, or override some classes?

Comment: @AdeelImran My final goal is for the children styles ('classes') to override styles applied by their parrent. This is not happening with material-ui because when you use `withStyles` it assigns higher specificity (priority) to styles produced by parrent. Technically, it means that `withStyles` generates parrent's styles after children's styles inside html `<head>` tag. So, my goal is to override parrent's styles. One way to do it would be modify the way my JSS gets generated.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do?  https://codesandbox.io/s/10pmn4yzrj

Comment: @LukePeavey Yes, that's excatly it! But how did you do it? Normally, `withStyles` applies children styles first and only then the parrents... You are not doing anything special there... What kind of black magic is this?

Comment: I'lll post an answer shortly

Comment: @drasto Im afraid i don't have a good solution for this.

Comment: @drasto In my example, it works because `Layout` uses props.children instead of directly including child components.  But this only works if child components are imported after parent. So not really a solution

Comment: @LukePeavey Thank you Luke! Let me know if some idea hits you and feel free to post it as an answer with some more details why you do not see a solution. If nothing else emerges I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a workaround than a solution...

Its possible to have the child component's styles injected below the parent's if you use `props.children` in the parent component.

[See JSS injection order](https://github.com/cssinjs/react-jss#injection-order)

```js
// If child components are imported after Layout,
// their styles will be injected below Layout's styles.
import Layout from "./Layout";
import ChildOne from "./ItemOne";
import ChildTwo from "./ItemTwo";

function App() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <ChildOne />
      <ChildTwo />
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Stack Overflow: Override styles set in parent component Material UI]

**Caveats**

Im not 100% sure that this behavior is guaranteed.

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting. It is a working solution but I am not sure I want to depend on import order for styling of my app...